# How to highlight lines that has diff with the base branch in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

The reason that sometimes I don't make a commit until the final version of changes will be ready is that I have lines of my changes highlighted in the IDE.
Is there a way to color a scrollbar or line number where resent changes has been made? (almost like annotate with Blame but without 5cm of workspace)

The case: I made a branch from develop. Cherry-picked some commits and making my changes.
So I have a tiny mark next to the lines that differs from develop and have a list of changed files.

Comment: The Git command line can show you anything you like, but it will color things the way Git colors them. Whether your IDE can show you what you like, colored the way your IDE colors them, depends on your IDE. So this is a question about Intellij-Idea, and not about Git.

Answer (score 0):

> . Is there a way to color a scrollbar or line number where resent changes has been made?

If you have your project listed under Preferences | Version Control | Directory Mappings
and you have enabled "Highlight modified lines in gutter"  in Preferences | Version Control | Confirmation

Then you should have color indication in a gutter, as [mentioned here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-changes-information.html#local_changes)

Comment: Yes, that. works fine until you make a commit. The ideal option is have similar highlight but for the diff with the base branch. Didn't find how to make that.

Comment: As an option, before commit you can go to bottom right corner "Branch" popup, then choose "base" branch and "Show Diff with Working tree"

Answer (score 0):

Install [Git Scope](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope) plugin

Unfortunately this feature is not available in the core IntelliJ and probably won't be in the nearest future. There is an [issue/feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24398) open since 2009